# Shell script to analyze files in multiple directories

Tags: shell

I am new to Unix and shell scripting, so hoping somebody can help me. I have a code that analyzes a file and then averages over several files (3 in the pared down example below). I submit my analysis code using the `bsub` command in the shell script. **My question is, how do I modify my script so that I can do the analysis, which entails averaging as mentioned, over all 3 files that are in different directories?** The only idea that comes to my mind is to copy each file to a separate directory and then doing all of the analysis there, but the files are huge, so copying them doesn't seem like the best idea. I'll be happy to clarify anything in case that's not clear.

```
#!/bin/sh

lsf_job_file="submit_analysis.lsf"

start=1
stop=3
increment=1

for id in $(seq $start $increment $stop)
do
    file_dir="${id}"
    cp -R base "${file_dir}"

    cd "${file_dir}"

    # Submit the job
    bsub < "${submit_analysis}"

    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Why do you think you'd need to copy anything at all?

Comment: ...if the concern is that you don't know how to refer to a file in a different directory, that's what _relative paths_ are for. `bsum <"$file_dir/$submit_analysis"` and then you don't need to do any `cd`ing around at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I don't see the `bsum` command on the IBM page (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=o-r). Is that part of LSF? Also, don't you need curly brackets around both file_dir and submit_analysis?

Comment: So I can do all this without the copying or cd'ing? And the lsf job file doesn't need to be in each directory?

Comment: "bsum" was a misread of "bsub" which you used in the question.

Comment: No, you don't need curly brackets for variable expansions except when you're parameterizing them or need to disambiguate where they end. For example, in `${foo}_$bar`, the curly braces are needed so it isn't interpreted as `${foo_}${bar}`, looking for a variable named `foo_` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Re: `lsf`, I don't know anything about it -- if you want folks with expertise in specific tools rather than just shell in general, you should tag your question with those tools.

Comment: ...btw, one thing you might consider in place of _copying_ files, if you do in fact need to care about what's in the current working directory, is _hardlinking_ files. Using `ln` to make a new name pointing to a file that's already on disk doesn't use any extra storage space and is basically instant. The only serious caveat about hardlinks is that they can't cross filesystem boundaries.